# that returns the sum of all numbers between two chosen numbers

Tags: javascript

I'm totally stuck at one excersise question. Can someone help me out with this question?

Create a function `sumRangeNumbers()` that returns the sum of all numbers
between two chosen numbers. The function should take two arguments, one
representing the lowest boundary and one that represents the highest
boundary. For example, the arguments 10 and 20 should return the sum of
10+11+12+13...+20.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 82; i++) {
  document.write(i + i + '+');
}
```

How do I write the loop that sums all the numbers with an function?

Comment: You're almost there. You need to have a variable to hold the sum, then increment that variable in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function sumRangeNumber (num1, num2) {
  let total = 0
  for (let i = num1; i <= num2; i++) {
    total += i
  }
  return total
}
```

You are on the right track with a for loop. What we did here was in place of declaring i as zero we passed the low value and in the comparison we pass the high value. This creates the range ie 10-20. From there each loop we add I too total which is declared outside fo the loop so as to not have it reset and we add to it.

As a previous comment mentioned, this is kinda doing your HW for you, so give the above function a shot and play around with it and change things to make sure you understand whats happening.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of DCR already provides a nice implementation and is probably what you were looking for. However, with a little mathematical knowledge you can make the function a little easier.

We know that the sum of 1 to n is `n(n+1)/2` by looking at [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF).

The sum of a to b, is simply the sum of 1 to b minus the sum of 1 to a - 1 (we also want to include a itself).

The sum between a and b is then `b(b + 1)/2 - (a - 1)(a)/2` and therefore your function becomes:

```js
const a = 10
const b = 20

function sumRangeNumbers(a, b) {
  const high = Math.max(a, b);
  const low = Math.min(a, b);

  return high * (high + 1) / 2 - (low - 1) * (low) / 2;
}

console.log(sumRangeNumbers(a, b)); // 165
console.log(sumRangeNumbers(b, a)); // 165
console.log(sumRangeNumbers(5, 7)); // 18
```

Comment: this on is computationally less intensive compared to all iterative approaches, however the `console.log` statement is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

you need to first create a function and then you need to call it.

```js
function sum(x,y){
var sum = 0;
for(let i = x;i<=y;i++){
   sum = sum + i;
}
console.log(sum)
}

sum(1,10);
```

Comment: I didn't think that we did people's homework for them.

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers belong to range of natural numbers, then why do you need a loop. Just use the fact that sum from low to high=

```
 ((high-low+1) * (low + high)) / 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const sumRange = (num1, num2) => (
  min = Math.min(num1, num2),
  Array(Math.abs(num1 - num2) + 1)
    .fill().map((_, i) => i + min)
    .reduce((sum, el) => sum + el, 0)
);

console.log(sumRange(20, 10));
console.log(sumRange(10, 20));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example using your current attempt. Keep in mind, you'll want to some error handling for cases where they give you an invalid high/low number.

IE:
`if (lowNum >= highNum) { console.error('invalid range'); }`

and maybe this too

`if (typeof lowNum !== 'number' && typeof highNum !== 'number') { console.error('Invalid inputs'); }`

```js
function sumUp(lowNum, highNum) {
  if (lowNum >= highNum) { throw new Error('Invalid Range'); }
  // Initialize total at 0
  let total = 0;
  // Loop through numbers between lowNum and highNum.
  // Do not include lowNum and highNum in the addition
  for (let i = lowNum + 1; i < highNum; i++) {
    // Increment the total with the 'in-between number (i)'
    total += i;
  }
  // Return the result
  return total;
}

// Test 1 (should be 44)
console.log(2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9, sumUp(1, 10));


// Test 2 (should be 315)
console.log(50 + 51 + 52 + 53 + 54 + 55, sumUp(49, 56));

// If you really want to do document.write
document.write(sumUp(49, 56));

// Test 3 (should fail)
console.log(sumUp(15, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sumRangeNumbers(lower, upper)  {
let total = 0;
for (let index=lower; index<=upper; index++) {
 total = total + index;
}
return total;
}

document.write(sumRangeNumbers(10,20));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
function sumRangeNumbers(from, to) {
  let result = 0;
  for (let i = from; i <= to; i++) {
    result += i;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
function getSum(x,y) {
    sum += x
    console.log(sum, x)
    if (x == y) { return sum }
    else { return getSum(x+1,y) }
}
sum = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, a for loop can be used to add each iteration to a final sum. Assigning parameters using Math.min() and Math.max() creates a boundary while letting user put in smaller or higher number first (more flexibility).

```
function sumAll(num1, num2) {
    let finalSum = 0;
    let min = Math.min(num1, num2)
    let max = Math.max(num1, num2)
    for (let i = min; i <= max; i++) {
         finalSum += i
    }
    return finalSum; 
    }
}
```